# how to count number of words in each column delimited by "|" seperator using hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

input data is

```
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|      movie_name      |             Genres             |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| digimon              | Adventure|Animation|Children's |
| Slumber_Party_Massac | Horror                         |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

i need output like

```
+----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
|      movie_name      |             Genres             | count_of_genres |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
| digimon              | Adventure|Animation|Children's |               3 |
| Slumber_Party_Massac | Horror                         |               1 |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
       ,size(split(coalesce(Genres,''),'[^|\\s]+'))-1  as count_of_genres

from    mytable
```

This solution covers varying use-cases, including -

- NULL values
- Empty strings
- Empty tokens (e.g. `Adventure||Animation` or`Adventure| |Animation` )

Answer (score 0):

This is a really, really bad way to store data.  You should have a separate `MovieGenres` table with one row per movie and per genre.

One method is to use `length()` and `replace()`:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + length(genres) - length(replace(genres, '|', ''))) as num_genres
from t;
```

This assumes that each movie has at least one genre.  If not, you need to test for that as well.